Making QMYSQL driver
I was trying to make QMYSQL driver using official site: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html#qmysql. I enter this to the command line:
qt-cmake -G Ninja "C:\Qt1\6.8.1\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\Qt1\6.8.1\msvc2022_64" -DMySQL_ROOT="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0"

and I get this:
CMake Error at C:/Qt1/6.8.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicSbomHelpers.cmake:2552 (message):
  No SBOM project name was set.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Qt1/6.8.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicSbomHelpers.cmake:2542 (_qt_internal_sbom_get_root_project_name_lower_case)
  C:/Qt1/6.8.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicSbomHelpers.cmake:2636 (_qt_internal_sbom_get_root_project_name_for_spdx_id)
  C:/Qt1/6.8.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicSbomHelpers.cmake:2603 (_qt_internal_sbom_generate_target_package_spdx_id)
  C:/Qt1/6.8.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicSbomHelpers.cmake:1926 (_qt_internal_sbom_record_target_spdx_id)
  C:/Qt1/6.8.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPluginHelpers.cmake:446 (_qt_internal_extend_sbom)
  mysql/CMakeLists.txt:8 (qt_internal_add_plugin)

I tried to add this command to the end of my request:
-DQT_NO_CREATE_SBOM=ON

Also I tried to add this:
set(QT_SBOM_PROJECT_NAME "mysql_driver")

in the CMakeList.txt from:
C:\Qt1\6.8.1\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql

I don't know what to do.

You can not mix MSVC and MinGW c++ libraries.

@chehrlic, thanks, I got it. What am I need to do next? Because I tried to find how do not mix these drivers and use only MSVC but I did not find the answer

What do you want to hear? Simply don't mix msvc and mingw c++ libs. Don't know what else to say.

@chehrlic, I just don't know how to make QMYSQL driver using only MSVC. I have already deleted the environment variables leading to mingw and it didn't help. My MSVC compiler is configured correctly.
